# Manifold with boundary and topological boundary

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Why aren't the topological boundary of a manifold with boundary and the boundary of the manifold the same sets?

We defined the boundary of a manifold as follows:

$\partial M:= \lbrace p \in M : \exists (U,\varphi) \text{chart with} \varphi (p)=(0,...,x_n)^T \rbrace$

In contrast to the topological boundary being the closure minus the interior of M.

Comment: Well, these are different definitions. If you have different definitions, your expectation should be that you might get different results. So your question should read: "why would they be the same"? One of the most common mistakes of beginners in math is to look at the name and draw conclusions from associations resulting from that name. It's the definition you have to look at.

Comment: Ok so it is caused by the different nature of the definition, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a simple example that lives in both situations.  If $X$ is any topological space, the topological boundary of $X$ is $\varnothing$.  Now, consider the case $X=[0,1]$ endowed with the inherited Euclidean subspace topology.  This is also the simplest example of a $1$-manifold with boundary.  As I said earlier, the topological boundary is $\varnothing$.  However, the manifold boundary is the $2$-point set $\{0,1\}$.  If you instead regard $[0,1]$ as a *subset* of the space $\mathbb{R}$ then its topological boundary is $\{0,1\}$, which is where your confusion lies.

Comment: Thank you very much for that example.

Answer (score 0):

The topological boundary equals the manifold boundary if and only if the manifold boundary is empty.

Explanation: Let $(X,T,A)$ be a manifold, i.e. let $T$ be a topology on $X$ and let $A$ be an atlas for $(X,T)$. The topological boundary - the boundary of $X$ with respect to $T$ - equals the manifold boundary - the boundary of $X$ with respect to $(T,A)$ - if and only if the manifold boundary is empty, since the topological boundary is always empty in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing apples with oranges.

The concept of topological boundary is a relative concept: given a topological space $X$ and a subset $Y \subset X$, the boundary of $Y$ relative to $X$ is, by definition, $\overline Y \cap \overline{X-Y}$. Very often "$X$" is given, and it is left out of the terminology, we narrow our attention to a specific subset of $X$, and we then think about the topological boundary of that subset; and this leads to great confusion which could be cleared up by emphasising that we are thinking about topological boundary of that subset **relative to $X$**.

Given a general topological space $X$, I suppose you *could* decide to define its topological boundary to be the boundary of $X$ relative to $X$, but that would be awfully boring, because it is always empty.